# In javascript how do i display different text depending on what the users points are?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user scores 30 points or more I want to display: *"You won"*, when the points are less than 30 I want to display: *"You lose"*. Here is part of my script code:

```
update_time: function() {
    this.time -= 1;
    if (this.time > 0) {
      if (String(this.time).length == 1) {
        this.time = "0" + this.time;
      }
      $(".info .time").html("00:" + this.time);
    } else {
      $(".info .time").html("00:00");
      clearInterval(this.time_interval);
      $(".end .score").html("Game over!<br />You scored " + this.points + " points!").parent().fadeIn("fast");
    }
  },

  add_point: function() {
    this.set_dot();
    this.points += 1;
    $(".info .points").html(this.points);
  },

  set_dot: function() {
    $(this.dot_selector).removeClass("active");
    var active = Math.floor((Math.random() * ($(this.dot_selector).length - 1))+1);
    $(this.dot_selector + ":eq("+active+")").addClass("active");
  }
};
```

Here is some html:

```
div class='info'>
  <div class='time'></div>
  <div class='points'></div>
</div>
<div class='wall'>
.....
<div class='dot'></div>
  <div class='dot'></div>
  <div class='dot'></div>
  <div class='start'>
    <button>Start game!</button>
  </div>
  <div class='end'>
    <div class='score'></div>
    <button>Play again!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot to mention the place where you want to show the text.

Comment: could you please add some html with this code? I have no idea what is bound to what element on your page or how your code is supposed to work.

Comment: I would like to show it with the game over and points display

Comment: I don't really know what the goal of this code is, but I tried something out, based on what I could read from this question: https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/du4wydue/

Comment: maybe this will help you understand what you need to do? The question is really unclear considering the code you provided. Maybe some screenshots would have helped.

Comment: Edited spelling/styling for better understanding. It doesn't really make sense to display "You lose" when the user hasn't finished the game. Displaying "You won" when he gets enough points if fine, but you may need to rethink that loosing part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code;

```
update_time: function() {
    this.time -= 1;
    if (this.time > 0) {
      if (String(this.time).length == 1) {
        this.time = "0" + this.time;
      }
      $(".info .time").html("00:" + this.time);
    } else {
      $(".info .time").html("00:00");
      clearInterval(this.time_interval);
      var pts = $(".points").html;
      alert(pts);
      if(pts<30){
          $(".end .score").html("Game over!<br />You scored " + this.points + " points!. You Lose").parent().fadeIn("fast");
      }else{
          $(".end .score").html("Game over!<br />You scored " + this.points + " points! You won").parent().fadeIn("fast");
      }
    }
},
```

Comment: This almost worked. but it is now saying "you win" even if you score less then 30.

Comment: what are the values of `this.points` and `.info .points` at the end of game?

Comment: add_point: function() {
    this.set_dot();
    this.points += 1;
    $(".info .points").html(this.points);
  },

Comment: what are the values?? i mean what are the contents of `this.points` and `.info .points`? what are the texts inside these html elements? i mean, is `this.points` has just the point, i mean the number alone?

Comment: this. point is just +1; info.points is the point you get when user clicks on a moving object...  i included the main html.

Comment: I have updated my code, and included an alert function. Tell me what that alert function shows / alerts. It will be helpful if you can show us a demo at jsfiddle.net